# How can I define circular referential integrity constraints?

Tags: mariadb, foreign-key, referential-integrity

I have two tables mutually referencing each other, and I get this error when trying to insert into one of them: "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed".

[image]

I have been stuck for three weeks this assignment and can't seem to get anywhere or find someone with database experience to help.

I have attached all three queries but only receive an error on the last query where I create the table "DEPARTMENTS"

```
CREATE DATABASE k0310855_AMAZON;

USE k0310855_AMAZON;
```

my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
EMP_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
EMP_SALARY int,
EMP_PHONE varchar(255),
EMP_DEPARTMENT varchar(255)
);
```

and:

```
CREATE TABLE CHILDREN (
    CHI_NAME int,
    CHI_AGE int,
    EMP_ID int,
    CONSTRAINT CHILDREN PRIMARY KEY (EMP_ID, CHI_NAME)
);
```

and:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENTS 
(
  EMP_DEPARTMENT int PRIMARY KEY,
  DEP_NAME varchar(255),
  DEP_BUDGET int,
  DEP_MANAGER varchar(255),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (DEP_MANAGER) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE 
(EMP_DEPARTMENT) 
);**
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `k0310855_AMAZON`.`DEPARTMENTS` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Comment: so is I am reading this correct this should resolve my issue?

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENTS (
    EMP_DEPARTMENT int PRIMARY KEY,
    DEP_NAME varchar(255),
    DEP_BUDGET int,
    DEP_MANAGER varchar(255),
   FOREIGN KEY (DEP_MANAGER) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (EMP_ID) 
);

Comment: Yep, but it remains weird for the PK of departments to be called "emp_department" iso. "Dep_id".

Answer (score 1):

To solve the chicken and egg problem that Vérace warned about, without manipulation of the constraints when a new department needs to be added, one could use a relation table, eg. dept_manager, iso. a reference from department to employee.

```
CREATE TABLE department
(
  dept_id      int PRIMARY KEY,
  dep_name     varchar(255),
  dep_budget   int,
  dep_manager  int NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE employee 
(
  emp_id      int PRIMARY KEY,
  emp_salary  int,
  emp_phone   varchar(255),
  emp_dep     int NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT emp_dep_fk FOREIGN KEY (emp_dep) REFERENCES department (dept_id)
);
create table dept_manager (
  dpm_id  int autoincrement primary key,
  dpm_department int not null,
  dpm_manager int not null,
  constraint dpm_dep_fk foreign key (dpm_department) references department,
  constraint dpm_emp_fk foreign key (dpm_manager) references employee
);
```

This would allow one to create departments, then employees, then register who manages the departments.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about solving your problem is this (all the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=94d0911249e1e57c1019b5e4d8a228d5)):

```
CREATE TABLE department
(
  dept_id      int PRIMARY KEY,
  dep_name     varchar(255),
  dep_budge    int,
  dep_manager int NOT NULL
);
```

and then:

```
CREATE TABLE employee 
(
  emp_id      int PRIMARY KEY,
  emp_salary  int,
  emp_phone   varchar(255),
  emp_dep    int NOT NULL,
  
  CONSTRAINT emp_dep_fk FOREIGN KEY (emp_dep) REFERENCES department (dept_id)
);
```

and finally,

```
CREATE TABLE children 
(
    child_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    child_dob  DATE        NOT NULL,
    emp_id     int         NOT NULL,

    child_age INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, child_dob, NOW())) VIRTUAL,

    CONSTRAINT kid_pk PRIMARY KEY (emp_id, child_name),
    CONSTRAINT kid_emp_fk FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES employee (emp_id)
);
```

We'll start with the children first!

You should **not** store `age` as a datum - `age` changes with time, so storing the age means that you would have to set up triggers to update this field every year - a **bad idea**!

Store the child's birthday as a `DATE` and then store its age as a [`GENERATED VIRTUAL`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/) field, and then the child's age will be calculated on the fly every time your select the record!

Example:

```
INSERT INTO children (child_name, child_dob, emp_id)
  VALUES ('Seán', '2015-12-05', 200);
```

and `SELECT * FROM children;` - result:

```
child_name  child_dob   emp_id   child_age
      Seán  2015-12-05     200           6
```

Now, for your more serious problem - the circular reference in your table declarations - you have `FOREIGN KEY` pointing back and forth.

AFAIK, MariaDB doesn't support `DEFERRED CONSTRAINT`s. The way to get around this is to input your data with fewer constraints and then **`ADD`** the constraint afterwards as follows (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=94d0911249e1e57c1019b5e4d8a228d5)):

```
ALTER TABLE department ADD CONSTRAINT dep_man_fk
FOREIGN KEY (dep_manager) REFERENCES employee (emp_id);
```

Or you could just use a decent RDBMS like PostgreSQL which does support [`DEFERRED CONSTRAINT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-set-constraints.html#:%7E:text=DEFERRED%20constraints%20are%20not%20checked,INITIALLY%20IMMEDIATE%2C%20or%20NOT%20DEFERRABLE.)s.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

Create both tables *without* the FKs.  Then do two `ALTER TABLEs` to add the FKs.

Plan B:  Circular constraints are usually a design error.  Rethink the schema.  Anyway, FKs are *not* required to have a database that works.

Comment: I don't see the error here.  An employee belongs to, works for a department.  Each department is managed by one employee.  Don't know if one employee can manage multiple departments, which in real life is possible, or if a department should be managed by an employee of the same department.